# How do I change the lower indexes (or subscripts) in the list of rules in a certain way?

Tags: list-manipulation

everyone! Can you please help me with the concise code?

Given a list of rules. setA =

```
{Subscript[Abx, 1, 1] -> 293.305, Subscript[Aby, 1, 1] -> -37.9087, 
 Subscript[Abz, 1, 1] -> -21.7755, Subscript[Abx, 1, 2] -> 306.777, 
 Subscript[Aby, 1, 2] -> -39.0271, Subscript[Abz, 1, 2] -> -17.8631, 
 Subscript[Abx, 1, 3] -> 305.999, Subscript[Aby, 1, 3] -> -20.5591, 
 Subscript[Abz, 1, 3] -> -13.3516, Subscript[Abx, 1, 4] -> 296.88, 
 Subscript[Aby, 1, 4] -> 7.90668, Subscript[Abz, 1, 4] -> -7.29044, 
 Subscript[Abx, 1, 5] -> 285.328, Subscript[Aby, 1, 5] -> 36.7819, 
 Subscript[Abz, 1, 5] -> 1.27108, Subscript[Abx, 1, 6] -> 277.254, 
 Subscript[Aby, 1, 6] -> 56.4782, Subscript[Abz, 1, 6] -> 13.2836, 
 Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] -> 329.509, Subscript[Aby, 2, 1] -> -45.9608, 
 Subscript[Abz, 2, 1] -> -7.54032, Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] -> 327.696, 
 Subscript[Aby, 2, 2] -> -34.1085, Subscript[Abz, 2, 2] -> -8.53138, 
 Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] -> 323.534, Subscript[Aby, 2, 3] -> -12.6589, 
 Subscript[Abz, 2, 3] -> -10.9313, Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] -> 317.955, 
 Subscript[Aby, 2, 4] -> 11.9279, Subscript[Abz, 2, 4] -> -11.7819, 
 Subscript[Abx, 2, 5] -> 311.89, Subscript[Aby, 2, 5] -> 33.1912, 
 Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] -> -8.12503, Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] -> 306.272, 
 Subscript[Aby, 2, 6] -> 44.6707, Subscript[Abz, 2, 6] -> 2.99749, 
 Subscript[Abx, 3, 1] -> 350.655, Subscript[Aby, 3, 1] -> -49.2378, 
 Subscript[Abz, 3, 1] -> -4.30901, Subscript[Abx, 3, 2] -> 344.377, 
 Subscript[Aby, 3, 2] -> -31.2548, Subscript[Abz, 3, 2] -> 0.0258388, 
 Subscript[Abx, 3, 3] -> 341.522, Subscript[Aby, 3, 3] -> -7.49589, 
 Subscript[Abz, 3, 3] -> -1.40915, Subscript[Abx, 3, 4] -> 339.678, 
 Subscript[Aby, 3, 4] -> 15.8155, Subscript[Abz, 3, 4] -> -3.88774, 
 Subscript[Abx, 3, 5] -> 336.432, Subscript[Aby, 3, 5] -> 32.4558, 
 Subscript[Abz, 3, 5] -> -2.68367, Subscript[Abx, 3, 6] -> 329.373, 
 Subscript[Aby, 3, 6] -> 36.2016, Subscript[Abz, 3, 6] -> 6.92931, 
 Subscript[Abx, 4, 1] -> 366.162, Subscript[Aby, 4, 1] -> -49.6521, 
 Subscript[Abz, 4, 1] -> -6.33289, Subscript[Abx, 4, 2] -> 361.216, 
 Subscript[Aby, 4, 2] -> -30.8016, Subscript[Abz, 4, 2] -> 5.72576, 
 Subscript[Abx, 4, 3] -> 360.739, Subscript[Aby, 4, 3] -> -5.8953, 
 Subscript[Abz, 4, 3] -> 7.90838, Subscript[Abx, 4, 4] -> 361.109, 
 Subscript[Aby, 4, 4] -> 17.9386, Subscript[Abz, 4, 4] -> 6.35521, 
 Subscript[Abx, 4, 5] -> 358.701, Subscript[Aby, 4, 5] -> 33.5719, 
 Subscript[Abz, 4, 5] -> 7.20654, Subscript[Abx, 4, 6] -> 349.895, 
 Subscript[Aby, 4, 6] -> 33.8762, Subscript[Abz, 4, 6] -> 16.6026, 
 Subscript[Abx, 5, 1] -> 385.45, Subscript[Aby, 5, 1] -> -49.1158, 
 Subscript[Abz, 5, 1] -> -7.8633, Subscript[Abx, 5, 2] -> 382.61, 
 Subscript[Aby, 5, 2] -> -33.0846, Subscript[Abz, 5, 2] -> 6.4856, 
 Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] -> 381.964, Subscript[Aby, 5, 3] -> -8.68214, 
 Subscript[Abz, 5, 3] -> 9.71485, Subscript[Abx, 5, 4] -> 381.309, 
 Subscript[Aby, 5, 4] -> 16.6662, Subscript[Abz, 5, 4] -> 8.9101, 
 Subscript[Abx, 5, 5] -> 378.447, Subscript[Aby, 5, 5] -> 35.5353, 
 Subscript[Abz, 5, 5] -> 11.157, Subscript[Abx, 5, 6] -> 371.175, 
 Subscript[Aby, 5, 6] -> 40.4998, Subscript[Abz, 5, 6] -> 23.541, 
 Subscript[Abx, 6, 1] -> 417.939, Subscript[Aby, 6, 1] -> -49.5409, 
 Subscript[Abz, 6, 1] -> -3.15155, Subscript[Abx, 6, 2] -> 412.956, 
 Subscript[Aby, 6, 2] -> -38.4393, Subscript[Abz, 6, 2] -> 0.222538, 
 Subscript[Abx, 6, 3] -> 405.973, Subscript[Aby, 6, 3] -> -16.6815, 
 Subscript[Abz, 6, 3] -> -3.29615, Subscript[Abx, 6, 4] -> 399.342, 
 Subscript[Aby, 6, 4] -> 10.3674, Subscript[Abz, 6, 4] -> -6.25992, 
 Subscript[Abx, 6, 5] -> 395.416, Subscript[Aby, 6, 5] -> 37.3421, 
 Subscript[Abz, 6, 5] -> -1.22105, Subscript[Abx, 6, 6] -> 396.55, 
 Subscript[Aby, 6, 6] -> 58.8777, Subscript[Abz, 6, 6] -> 19.2682}
```

. I need to create four functions, which should make such changes as: 1) swap the first and second index of each rule, for example, `Subscript[Abx, 3, 5]` should become `Subscript[Abx, 5, 3]`. 2) The second function should change the first index to the opposite from the end. All indexes vary from 1 to 6, so, the function has to change each item like that `Subscript[Abx, 2, 3]` to `Subscript[Abx, 5, 3]` and so on. 3) The third function should make the same changes with the second index, so `Subscript[Abx, 2, 3]` changes to `Subscript[Abx, 2, 4]`. 4) The fourth function changes simultaneously both indexes to the opposite ones, so `Subscript[1, 3]` becomes `Subscript[6, 4]`.

I know ho to do this manipulating with the list like

```
Table[Subscript[setA[[i]][[1]][[1]], setA[[i]][[1]][[2]], 
      setA[[i]][[1]][[3]]], {i, 1, Length@setA}].
```

But I think it is ugly and inefficient.. Can you please help me with an elegant and efficient implementation of these functions in the style of Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

Define the 4 functions like:

```
fun1[dat_] := dat /. Subscript[x0_, x1_, x2_] :> Subscript[x0, x2, x1];
fun2[dat_] := dat /. Subscript[x0_, x1_, x2_] :> Subscript[x0, 7 - x1, x2];
fun3[dat_] := dat /. Subscript[x0_, x1_, x2_] :> Subscript[x0, x1, 7 - x2];
fun4[dat_] := dat /. Subscript[x0_, x1_, x2_] :> Subscript[x0, 7 - x1, 7 - x2];
```

Then test like:

```
fun1[Subscript[Abx, 3, 5]]
(* Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] *)

fun2[Subscript[Abx, 2, 3]]
(* Subscript[Abx, 5, 3] *)

fun3[Subscript[Abx, 2, 3]]
(* Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] *)

fun4[Subscript[Abx, 1, 3]]
(* Subscript[Abx, 6, 4] *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the last question a little bit off topic. In the given list how to refer to the value of a rule with a known left-hand side? I mean, how to find for example the value of Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] that is -8.12503?

Comment: P.S. And the really last question. In the result of fun2[setA] how to sort the list like it was originally?

Comment: Assuming lrules is the list of rules, you get the value of Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] by: `Subscript[Abz, 2, 5] /. lrules `

Comment: The order of the list is not changed by the functions.

Comment: Thank you! ))))